# hilo vs GUIDcomb vs Sequence

Tags: database, hibernate, database-design, jpa

Is there any practical experience using the hilo generator for a VERY large number of records? In practice, if you or, for example, restarting your server once a day what ends up being the number of unique rows you can get in a in64 PKEY?

How does this compare to GUIDcomb or a plain old Postgresql sequence generator with a larger allocation size (say 500).

Say I want the ability to map the world's population at some point, I don't want to run out of ids, what are some good general rules for mixing performance versus not running out of identities? Speed of generation would also be a factor.

Currently, it seems to me that there are no clear advantages over a regular old sequence generator with a reasonable allocation size. But I don't know a lot about this subject.

Comment: Whatever the way the ID is generated, a 64-bit integer is always 64 bits, and the number of possible IDs is always the same. Assuming you only use positive numbers you have around 9E18 IDs. The world population is around 9E9. So you have a very, very, very large margin.

Comment: So wouldn't a sequence with an good sized allocation be best? What advantages does hilo have over sequence?

Comment: There are two ways to avoid executing a SQL query each time you need an ID from a sequence. 1. get the next value, have the sequence increment itself by (for example) 50, cache the 50 next IDs, and re-execute a query once the bucket of 50 IDs is exhausted. This requires that the generator and the sequence are both synchronized to use the same increment/bucket size. 2. Assume the sequnce increments by 1, multiply the value by 50 and return the next 50 numbers, then reincrement the sequence by 1. That's the hilotechnique, which simply assumes that the sequence is incremented by 1.

Comment: In the end, the result is the same. Choose the technique that you like the most. The default technique used by Hibernate is the second one (hilo). I don't even remember if it supports the first one natively.